# How do I pass multiple search parameters in node js URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, routes

I'm using react, node, express, postgress. How would I go about using express routes to pass multiple parameters? for example:

This is my route:

```
//Get entries from materials2 table
app.get("/materials2/:id1&:id2", async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const {material_thickness, material_width} = req.params;
        const contact = await pool.query(
            `SELECT *
            FROM materials_inventory
            WHERE
                (material_thickness = $1) AND
                (material_width BETWEEN ($2-0.5) AND ($2+0.5))`, [material_thickness, material_width]); 


        res.json(contact.rows[0]);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})
```

The idea is that I need to pass two parameters to the search query

From the react side I have:

```
const stateSetter = async (thickness, width, length, length2) => {
        try {
            
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/materials/${thickness, width}`, [thickness, width])
            const jsonData = await response.json();

            console.log(thickness);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }
```

So the idea is that stateSetter receives some values, uses those with the route. How can I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: `:id1` is a path parameter, not a query parameter. You can access query paramters with [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

Comment: @jabaa thanks for the suggestion, could you clarify how that would like like? something along the lines of: ```req.query.id1 = material_thickness``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request query`. Change the route in node like so:

```
//Get entries from materials2 table
app.get("/materials2", async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const {materialThickness, materialWidth} = req.query;
        const contact = await pool.query(
            `SELECT *
            FROM materials_inventory
            WHERE
            (material_thickness = $1) AND
            (material_width BETWEEN ($2-0.5) AND ($2+0.5))`, [materialThickness, materialWidth]); 


        res.json(contact.rows[0]);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})
```

And you call in the frontend like so:

```
const stateSetter = async (thickness, width, length, length2) => {
    try {
        
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/materials2?materialThickness=${thickness}&materialWidth=${width}`)
        const jsonData = await response.json();

        console.log(thickness);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}
```

Also, you were calling the endpoint `materials` form you frontend, but specified it as `materials2` in node. I updated that in the answer but keep in mind.